# Copy entire tree of an object in Eclipse Debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When I am on Eclipse debug mode, I would like to copy the entire tree of an object. Is there an easy way to do it?

The object has several structures and hashmaps nested inside it. So expanding every entry is tedious process.

I would like to copy the entire object and then later inspect it. How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: To inspect it later, I would print it to (many) A4 or copy output to an external editor.  I provided a good toString to every class.  It is not a perfect solution though.  By the way, it is a good question. :)

Answer (score 1):

you could serialize the object graph to a file -- if all of the connected obejcts are serializable.

I have done this myself by writing a `TestUtils.serialize(Serializable, String)` method. i have used internally apache's SerializationUtils  and where the string is a file path.

use this when execution has stopped on a breakpoint:

1. open the display view
2. call the `serialize()` method with the appropriate args

later you can deserialze the file to the object graph again (e.g. in a unit test ) and then inspect it or extract portions of it or whatever.

if not all objects are serializable you need to beef up your `serialize()` to handle these cases or use some other generic serialization library that can handle such stuff.

other alternatives are, but probably insufficient for your problem:

- write a custom to `string()` for the debug/expression view that only contains the really needed values
- use a screenshot tool like greenshot

Comment: @iehrlich what do u mean ? a) shortages like 'u' OR b) the garbled markdown of my list of alternatives, that i have now fixed, so it appears as bullet OR c) smth else that iäm missing?

Comment: We're trying to use the conventional English language on that site. For examples of proper spelling, please consider taking a look at... virtually, any other message. With such spelling, your post(s) will be most likely flagged and removed.

Comment: @iehrlich thx for the info, fixed my text accordingly, but: where is a page that lays out the conventions regarding abbreviations, since you use "pls" yourself ?

Comment: Well, I think [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322657/how-to-treat-bad-english-sentence-syntax-and-typo-hell) is a good topic to get the general idea :)